# Get the first week day in a given week number in PHP

Tags: php, date, calendar

How can I get the first week day in a given week number?
I'm making a function in PHP for a calendar app.

The idea: When I click on a link that basically uses strtotime with +1 month it only jumps to that same day of course. I need to get the week numbers correct.

Example: When I use the menu to move from August to September, it shouldn't select the same date I was in in August, but the first day of the first week number in September (Monday, 2th of September, week number 36).

And from September to October: Week number 40, Tuesday the 1th of October.

Comment: Could you write to question your date output format? You just have only year `2013` and week number `40`?

Comment: @Bora Yes. The whole idea is that the calendar should check which is the legit first day in a given week number. So basically if I wanted to fetch the first week day in the week number 40, it should return the right week day, not always Monday :) The year is crucial of course since the week days aren't always the same on every year.

Comment: ISO weeks always start with Monday. Week number 40 of 2013 starts on Monday 30th September 2013. How are you defining a "legit first day"?

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/ Actually the week that has Thursday in it (or in other words: 4 days out of 3) will decide on which month will it occur. So Week number 40 doesn't start with Monday 30th of September, but 1st of October (Tuesday). At least that's how it here (in Finland). The calendars look like this: http://www.paivyri.fi/ . From there you can see how weeks should shift in my code.

Comment: No, week 40 on year 2013 starts at 30th September. That is correct. I understand you need something else, but ISO weeks start on monday, you like it or not. If I understand you, you need first-next-date if week is in 2 different months?

Answer (score 3):

I found a function that exactly like you want it. This is `setISODate`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate(2013, 35, 1);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can change `Y-m-d` date format as you want

#### Output

```
2013-08-26 // This week number and monday
```

#### Usage

```
setISODate(year, week, day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
        $week = 3;
        $year = 2009;

        $timestamp = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  $year ) + ( $week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
        $timestamp_for_monday = $timestamp - 86400 * ( date( 'N', $timestamp ) - 1 );
        $date_for_monday = date( 'Y-m-d', $timestamp_for_monday );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like every1 already said, ISO weeks start with monday. Quote from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date : `Weeks start with Monday.`

### If I understand your problem correctly, you need first-next-date in next month if selected week is in 2 different months?

```
function getFirstWeekDay($year, $week) {
    $dt = (new DateTime)->setISODate($year, $week, 1);
    $dtC = clone $dt;
    for ($N = $dt->format('N'); $N < 7; $N++) {
        $dtC->modify('+1 day');
        if ($dt->format('m') !== $dtC->format('m')) {
            return $dtC;
        }
    }
    return $dt;
}

echo getFirstWeekDay(2013, 40)->format('W\t\h \w\e\e\k \i\s Y-m-d'); 
# 40th week is 2013-10-01

echo getFirstWeekDay(2013, 1)->format('W\t\h \w\e\e\k \i\s Y-m-d'); 
# 1th week is 2013-01-01
```